# python async with requests function in webcam loop

Tags: python, opencv, asynchronous

I am new to async in python and openCV.

I am working on sending an image from a webcam to a server and getting the value.

However, the following code does not work asynchronously.

It only sends one frame, receives one result, and then renders the next frame.

I'm hoping the webcam rendering will continue.

And I want to send the next frame when I get the result value from the server.

What am I missing?

```
import cv2
import os
import time
import threading
import numpy as np

import argparse
import requests
import base64
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def faceanlyzer(image):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        string = base64.b64encode(cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)[1]).decode()
        data = {
                "image": string 
            }
        url = "http://localhost:5000/streamdata"

        async with session.post(url, data = data) as resp:
            result = await resp.json()
            print(result)

async def main():
    cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:

        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        image = cv2.resize(frame, dsize=(640, 480), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        
        await faceanlyzer(image)

        cv2.imshow('Video', cv2.resize(image,(1300,1000),interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC))
        
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break  

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: DO NOT base64-encode binary data for a HTTP request. DO NOT wrap binary data of this size in JSON. YOU control that server, so you should implement an API that accepts binary data instead of JSON.

Comment: async/await still makes *your code* synchronous. as long as the request isn't done, the code _depending on it_ (everything after it) will wait. you'll have to read more about async/await.